# How can I find all Markdown links using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, markdown

In Markdown there is two ways to place a link, one is to just type the raw link in, like: `http://example.com`, the other is to use the `()[]` syntax: `(Stack Overflow)[http://example.com ]`.

I'm trying to write a regular expression that can match both of these, and, if it's the second match to also capture the display string.

So far I have this:

```
(?P<href>http://(?:www\.)?\S+.com)|(?<=\((.*)\)\[)((?P=href))(?=\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P8VEk6XYDfWFZ9pt)

But this doesn't seem to match either of my two test cases in Debuggex:

```
http://example.com
(Example)[http://example.com]
```

Really not sure why the first one isn't matched at the very least, is it something to do with my use of the named group? Which, if possible I'd like to keep using because this is a simplified expression to match the link and in the real example it is too long for me to feel comfortable duplicating it in two different places in the same pattern.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this not doable at all?

**EDIT:** I'm doing this in Python so will be using their regex engine.

Comment: What regex engine/language will you use?

Comment: The Python one! Sorry, should have clarified, will edit the question now..

Comment: Minor point but you have your markdown brackets in the wrong order - it should be `[Text](http://url)` - so `[]` before `()`

Comment: There's another way to add links by reference, e.g. `[link]` in one line and `[link]: http://...` somewhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your pattern doesn't work is here: `(?<=\((.*)\)\[)` since the re module of Python doesn't allow variable length lookbehind.

You can obtain what you want in a more handy way using [the new regex module of Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) *(since the re module has few features in comparison)*.

Example: `(?|(?<txt>(?<url>(?:ht|f)tps?://\S+(?<=\P{P})))|\(([^)]+)\)\[(\g<url>)\])`

[An online demo](http://regex101.com/r/mL3hA8/1)

pattern details:

```
(?|                                       # open a branch reset group
    # first case there is only the url
    (?<txt>                               # in this case, the text and the url  
        (?<url>                           # are the same
            (?:ht|f)tps?://\S+(?<=\P{P})
        )
    )
  |                                       # OR
    # the (text)[url] format
    \( ([^)]+) \)                         # this group will be named "txt" too 
    \[ (\g<url>) \]                       # this one "url"
)
```

This pattern uses the branch reset feature `(?|...|...|...)` that allows to preserve capturing groups names (or numbers) in an alternation. In the pattern, since the `?<txt>` group is opened at first in the first member of the alternation, the first group in the second member will have the same name automatically. The same for the `?<url>` group.

`\g<url>` is a reference to the named subpattern `?<url>` (like an alias, in this way, no need to rewrite it in the second member.)

`(?<=\P{P})` checks if the last character of the url is not a punctuation character (useful to avoid the closing square bracket for example). *(I'm not sure of the syntax, it may be `\P{Punct}`)*

Comment: @Unihedron: `ftps` is not handle by IETF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) but it is possible.

Comment: Is there a standard Python markdown library that allows to retrieve links? It feels like a better approach than writing complex regular expressions on our own.

Comment: It does not math `[foo](#some-internal-link)` and it does not match too url without space between them (like `[foo](http://bla.com).[bla](http://ddd.com)`. With space after dot, it matches. Can you solve it?

Comment: @somenxavier: you have permuted square and round brackets in your examples. About internal links, nothing forbids to build either a more descriptive or a more leniant subpattern for urls. The one I used in my example is minimal and doesn't handle all kinds of urls. (Note that a pattern that handle all urls is one page long).