# Extracting URL and anchor text from Markdown using Python

Tags: python, regex, markdown

I am attempting to extract anchor text and associated URLs from Markdown. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109307/189134) question. Unfortunately, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109573/189134) doesn't seem to fully answer what I want.

In Markdown, there are two ways to insert a link:

#### Example 1:

```markdown
[anchor text](http://my.url)
```

#### Example 2:

```markdown
[anchor text][2]

   [1]: http://my.url
```

---

My script looks like this (note that I am using [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), not re):

```
import regex
body_markdown = "This is an [inline link](http://google.com). This is a [non inline link][4]\r\n\r\n  [1]: http://yahoo.com"

rex = """(?|(?<txt>(?<url>(?:ht|f)tps?://\S+(?<=\P{P})))|\(([^)]+)\)\[(\g<url>)\])"""
pattern = regex.compile(rex)
matches = regex.findall(pattern, body_markdown, overlapped=True)
for m in matches:
    print m
```

This produces the output:

```
('http://google.com', 'http://google.com')
('http://yahoo.com', 'http://yahoo.com')
```

My expected output is:

```
('inline link', 'http://google.com')
('non inline link', 'http://yahoo.com')
```

---

How can I properly capture the anchor text from Markdown?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> How can I properly capture the anchor text from Markdown?

Parse it into a structured format (e.g., html) and then use the appropriate tools to extract link labels and addresses.

```
import markdown
from lxml import etree

body_markdown = "This is an [inline link](http://google.com). This is a [non inline link][1]\r\n\r\n  [1]: http://yahoo.com"

doc = etree.fromstring(markdown.markdown(body_markdown))
for link in doc.xpath('//a'):
  print link.text, link.get('href')
```

Which gets me:

```
inline link http://google.com
non inline link http://yahoo.com
```

The alternative is writing your own Markdown parser, which seems like the wrong place to focus your effort.

Comment: An example (dependabot PR in github) which renders correctly, but the other answers fail on it: 
<li>perf: read in_hot_standby GUC on connection [PR <a href="https://github-redirect.dependabot.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/2334">#2334</a>](<a href="https://github-redirect.dependabot.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/2334">pgjdbc/pgjdbc#2334</a>)</li>

Comment: Wonderful solution, just beware of (treat) lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError exception if there are mixed HTML comments on your markdown:
`<!--- something something  [label text](http://my_url)(something something) -->`

Answer (score 3):

Modifying @mreinhardt solution to return a list (and not a dict) of all pairs `(text, link)`:

```
import re
    
INLINE_LINK_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)')
FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\[(\d+)\]')
FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\]:\s+(\S+)')


def find_md_links(md):
    """ Return dict of links in markdown """

    links = list(INLINE_LINK_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_links = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_urls = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE.findall(md))

    for key in footnote_links.keys():
        links.append((footnote_links[key], footnote_urls[footnote_links[key]]))

    return links
```

I test in python3 with [repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734682/extracting-url-and-anchor-text-from-markdown-using-python/30738268#comment112048716_30738268) links as:

```markdown
[h](http://google.com) and [h](https://goog.e.com)
```

Comment: It will also find following structure in the code such as

int main[t](int a)

Comment: it will also not support the [[source]](link)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a couple simple `re` patterns:

```
import re

INLINE_LINK_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)')
FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE = re.compile(r'\[([^\]]+)\]\[(\d+)\]')
FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE = re.compile(r'\[(\d+)\]:\s+(\S+)')


def find_md_links(md):
    """ Return dict of links in markdown """

    links = dict(INLINE_LINK_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_links = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_TEXT_RE.findall(md))
    footnote_urls = dict(FOOTNOTE_LINK_URL_RE.findall(md))

    for key, value in footnote_links.iteritems():
        footnote_links[key] = footnote_urls[value]
    links.update(footnote_links)

    return links
```

Then you could use it like:

```
>>> body_markdown = """
... This is an [inline link](http://google.com).
... This is a [footnote link][1].
...
... [1]: http://yahoo.com
... """
>>> links = find_md_links(body_markdown)
>>> links
{'footnote link': 'http://yahoo.com', 'inline link': 'http://google.com'}
>>> links.values()
['http://yahoo.com', 'http://google.com']
```

Comment: This will fail with common Markdown constructs such as `This is a [footnote link][].\n\n[footnote link]: http://google.com/'`

Comment: Interesting, thanks @larsks for pointing that out since it wasn't stated in the initial question statement. That would be easy enough to fix, but if there are a lot of special cases (I don't know markdown well enough) then using a proper parser would indeed be better. It just seemed like a lot of overhead to use one if this simple task was the only thing he needed to do though.

Comment: It fails with this `body_markdown = """this is [foo](http://hola.com). And [bla](#hols).[foo](http://hoo)"""`. The results has only the last `foo`: `links
{'foo': 'http://hoo', 'bla': '#hols'}`. Perhaps changing dict to list somewhere fix the problem?

Comment: @mreinhardt Can you help me. I think your solution could be easyly modificable to fit my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197371/detecting-all-links-in-markdown-files-in-python-and-replace-them-with-outputs-of) using re module. Thanks in advance.